# CSS stylesheet path form limitation?

Tags: css

`<link href="http://example.com/example.php?id=0&grab=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.org%2Fcss%2Fmaster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />` - is that URL allowed? Any MIME type requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is that URL allowed?

I don't see why not: Standard rules for valid URLs apply.

> Any MIME type requirements?

It should emit `content-type: text/css`, otherwise Firefox won't recognize the style sheet even if you specify it in the `link` tag.